# Scroll bar positioning in CSS

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar

[image]Is there any javascript/jquery available to take position of vertical scroll bar of an overflow scroll div to fix a position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use a jquery method scrollTop():

```
$("#id1").scrollTop();
```

It returns a position of a scroll bar's roller.

Also you can get a height of the scroll bar:

```
$("#id1").scrollHeight;
```